# upload to Amazon S3 extremely slow

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I upload files from .NET environment using aws .net sdk.
The code runs on EC2 small instance server.
The code is very straightforward and standard.

The problem is that uploading ~10Mb file takes about 10 minutes, which in my opinion is not good 
File at about 7-8Mb takes about 7-8 minutes respectively.

What can be done to improve this issue?

Comment: There must be something seriously broken, uploading to S3 should be lightning fast from an EC2 instance (i.e. within their network) - care to show us your _very straightforward and standard_ code for review (the relevant fragments at least)?

Comment: Sure, here it is. Btw, unfortunately uploading to S3 is not so lightning fast as you think. It probably depends on instance type as every type has its i/o limitations.
Anyway the code is:
           
`PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.WithBucketName(bucketName);
request.WithKey(fileName);
request.WithInputStream(ms);
AmazonS3 S3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(S3AccessKey, S3SecretKey);
S3Client.PutObject(request);`

Comment: I'm aware of the instance type I/O implications - maybe I've put too much color into my comment via _lightning fast_, however, I simply wanted to stress that what you are experiencing is waaaay too sloooow ;) For some perspective you might want to read the often cited RightScale analysis of [Network performance within Amazon EC2 and to Amazon S3](http://blog.rightscale.com/2007/10/28/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3/), which concludes: _The bottom line [...] is that Amazon is providing very high throughput around EC2 and S3. [...] this is a ton of bandwidth all around._

Comment: I'm having the same problem with mind-bogglingly slow uploads to S3, though I'm using PHP from a large EC2 instance. I also get this slowness from the server running on my laptop and accessing the same S3 bucket.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What is your CPU load during the upload? If you have SSL turned on, then it could be that your are maxing out the tiny amount of CPU that your EC2 instance is allowed to consume.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've been able to find for remedying this odd upload speed problem is to disable SSL. This is, obviously, a very bad idea, since you'll be sending your AWS credentials in cleartext, but it really does make a **huge** difference in upload speed. I wish I could find some other solution.